# WCSession transferUserInfo only works in Foreground

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchos-2

I am using WCSession's `tranferUserInfo` to send data between the watch and the iOS app for info that needs to be handled when either product is in the background.  This works 100% of the time on the simulator but never with actual devices.

By using breakpoints I have discovered that `func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject])` is never called in the background but is immediately called when the app is brought to the foreground.  Clearly `session.transferUserInfo(data)` is being called but not received in the background state.  Again running the exact same code but on the simulator works perfectly.

I am running iOS 9.3.2 and Watch OS 2.2.1. Clearly this function was meant to handle communications in the background state and thus I believe the simulator is working as intended.  I tried wrapping both the sender and receiver in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {` block, but to no avail.

What am I missing about `transferUerInfo` and its seeming inability to work properly with background states?

FYI - breakpoint set at the beginning of `didRecieveUserInfo` is never hit until the app is brought into the foreground.

```
func transferInfo(data:[String: AnyObject])
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 2.2, *)
            {
                if #available(iOS 9.3, *)
                {
                    if self.session.activationState == .Activated
                    {
                        self.session.transferUserInfo(data)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("alertError", object: self, userInfo: ["error":"Failed to transfer"])
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    self.session.transferUserInfo(data)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                self.session.transferUserInfo(data)
            }
        })
    }

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            for delegate in self.watchCommsProtocols
            {
                delegate.watchCommsDidUpdateInfo!(userInfo)
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just watched the Watch Connectivity session from WWDC 2015.  It seems that `transferUserInfo` cannot be received by iOS until the app is in the foreground.  That is of course what I am seeing with actual devices.  The issue here then, and what has thrown me off, is that the simulator as of this writing DOES receive these messages when in the background.  This is not the correct behavior and should therefore be considered a bug in the functioning of the simulator.

For my purposes I should be able to use `sendMessage`from the watch to iOS when iOS is in the background.  However, the same is not true in reverse.  To use `sendMessage` from iOS to the watch, the watch will have to be in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Both sides can send while the sending app is in background.

This means

- if you are sending while there is no connection,
- then your sending app goes into background or stops,
- then there is a connection
- -> the sending OS will send.

An app in watchOS 2 can't do anything in background. So it can't receive.

On iOS, an app can't bring itself to the foreground while in background. So dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() doesn't make sense here.

Comment: In this case I am looking at the iOS side being able to receive and process what the watch sends when it is in the background.  On the sim both receives (watch and iOS) trigger the receive breakpoint when in the background.  However, sticking with iOS it does not trigger a receive until brought to the foreground (with the watch always in the foreground).  I agree the main thread code shouldn't be needed I added it as I know some replies here would recommend it and I wanted to show up front that it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Why do you want to receive in background when you can't bring your app to foreground?

Comment: There is a message sent from the watch to the phone telling it to start a timer and also to start tracking things like distance using the GPS.  I'd like them to be able to kick that process off from the watch and not have to go to the phone.  Then when they go to the phone, this information is there.  As it is, the phone won't get that signal until it enters the foreground. On the sim though the signal is received when the app is in the background and so works as I'd hoped.